Generalizing Wave Equation to two strings connected at a point
Hi physics noob here with a question about strings.
I saw that you can derive the wave equation assuming an increasing density of masses and increasing spring constants in a 1-dimensional system of couple harmonic oscillators on a ring here: Classical Field Theory - Continuum limit in forming the Lagrangian density and the elasticity modulus
I would like to think about the generalized problem where we take two one-dimensional systems of oscillators, say two rings, but we identify a mass in each system so that the rings are connected and no longer independent.

Is there a similar argument to derive the Lagrangian of the continuum limit of the system?
Also as far as I am aware, the continuum limit being connected rings is not a manifold since at the shared point between the two rings, there is no neighborhood locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ while everywhere else is. Do these more general objects have a name I could search for?

